Lombok constructor annotations not working in Java 23
The Lombok annotations are not working in NetBeans 23 with Java 23. I'm using Spring Boot.
I receive this error:
com/veryona/jogos/controller/JogoController.java:[27,22] constructor Console in class com.veryona.jogos.model.Console cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found:    java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

This is what is in class JogoController:
List<Jogo> jogos = new ArrayList();
List<Console> consoles = new ArrayList();

@GetMapping("/menu")
public String mostrarMenu(Model model) {
    
    consoles.add(new Console("PS3", "Sony", "PlayStation 3"));
    consoles.add(new Console(
            "X360",
            "MicroSoft",
            "Xbox 360"
    ));
    consoles.add(new Console(
            "NWii",
            "Nintendo",
            "Wii"
    ));
    
    model.addAttribute("consoles", consoles);
    model.addAttribute("jogos", jogos);
    return "index";
}

Console class:
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Console {
    
    String ID;
    String empresa;
    String nome;
}

I tried to do without the annotation @NoArgsConstructor and I receive the same error
My pom file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.veryona</groupId>
    <artifactId>jogos</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>jogos</name>
    <description>databank de jogos</description>
    <url/>
    <licenses>
        <license/>
    </licenses>
    <developers>
        <developer/>
    </developers>
    <scm>
        <connection/>
        <developerConnection/>
        <tag/>
        <url/>
    </scm>
    <properties>
        <java.version>23</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>

I just want insert the data in my list with the constructor made by Lombok.

Possibly related: [FEATURE] JDK 23 compatibility #3722 (issue is open as of this comment)

Also possibly related: [BUG] Error in JDK 23, does it support JDK 23? and Using Lombok Library With JDK 23

@ThomasKläger Why not make  an Answer of your Comment?

@ThomasKläger I have try to set 'maven.compiler.proc' to full, it compile without error, however, the getter, setter would work in runtime.

This question is similar to: Build Failure: @Data Annotation won't regonize by Maven. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Add Lombok plugin to IDE. It works for me.
